# How to disable Google asking permission to regularly check installed apps on my phone?

Tags: android, permissions, privacy, policy

I'm developing an Android app, which I therefore endlessly build and install on my test device. Since a couple days I get with every build/install a question asking

> Google may regularly check installed apps for potentially harmfull
>   behaviour. Learn more in Google Settings > Verify apps.

I get the option to Accept or Decline. I've declined about a hundred times now, but it seems to be Googles policy to keep on asking until I get sick of the message and finally click Accept. But I don't want that!

So my question: how do I let Google know once and for all that I do not want them regularly checking installed apps on my phone?

Comment: Particularly need a solution for this to support automated UI testing, e.g. with Espresso, because the APK can't even be installed on a new emulator instance unless the Accept/Decline button is clicked.  Is there a `@Rule` like `GrantPermissionRule` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/GrantPermissionRule.html) for this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

On Android prior to 4.2, go to **Google Settings**, tap **Verify apps** and uncheck the option **Verify apps**.

On Android 4.2+, uncheck the option **Settings > Security > Verify apps** and/or **Settings > Developer options > Verify apps over USB**.

Comment: Ah! I just now see it under Settings > Developer Options > Verify apps over USB.. Sorry, I just got so sick of this message and the fact that I couldn't find the setting..

Comment: Not in Settings app find the `Google Settings` app on your phone.

Comment: Ah, and I had never heared of the Google settings app either.. Cheers!

Comment: It's the default settings app ;)

Comment: On Android 5 I had to use the Google Settings app. Verify apps over USB was grayed out in the Developer options.

Comment: For me too on 4.2.2.

Comment: Can someone edit the answer to include instructions for MIUI?

Answer (score 22):

If you want to turn off app verification programmatically, you can do so with the following code:

```
boolean success = true;
boolean enabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "package_verifier_enable", 1) == 1;
if (enabled) {
    success = Settings.Secure.putString(context.getContentResolver(), "package_verifier_enable", "0");
}
```

You will also need the following system permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Also worth noting is that the "package_verifier_enable" string comes from the `Settings.Glabal.PACKAGE_VERIFIER_ENABLE` member which seems to be inaccessible.

Comment: This code is not working, always returning true, though, I've disabled "verify app" from settings. Do you've any workaround @ThelIT?

Comment: @Pankaj, was the app installed as a system app?

Comment: @TheIT No, my app is a simple app which will be uploaded to playstore later. But as security recomandation, customer saying to check for "app verify" and if it's not enabled, then prompt to user to enable it and navigate user to setting page.

Answer (score 10):

It is also available in general settings

Settings -> Security -> Verify Apps

Just un-check it.

( I am running 4.2.2 but most probably it should be available in 4.0 and higher. Cant say about previous versions ... )

Comment: On M it is in the Developer Options menu

Answer (score 10):

On Android 5.1 Lollipop for my device, click on the `Google Settings` icon > `Security` > `Scan device for security threats` .

Note that `Google Settings` is separated from the `Settings` app itself.

Answer (score 9):

If the device is rooted,

```
root@mako:/ # settings put global package_verifier_enable 0
```

Seems to do the trick.

[image]

Comment: This does work, however I did notice that after the device rebooted the setting was reset to enabled.

Comment: Yeah. Why is it reset? Irritating.

Answer (score 3):

On Android 5.0+

Settings > More > Developer Options > Uncheck "Verify apps via USB"!

[image]

Comment: Main app settings? I don't see a More in the main Android Settings, or in Google Chrome settings

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me ...

On Android 4.2+, uncheck the option Settings > Security > Verify apps and/or Settings > Developer options > Verify apps over USB.

Answer (score 2):

On Android 6+ follow this path:
Settings -> Google -> Security -> Verify Apps
Uncheck them all! Now you're good to GO!!!

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of Lollipop, go into app. drawer and look for Google Settings. Scroll down to Security, tap iit to open, slide to the left the slider next to 'Improve harmful app. detection' to the left, then same for 'Scan device for security threats'. Exit out of that, and the annoying pop up will never appear again!

Answer (score 1):

In Nexus 5, Go to **Settings** -> **Google** -> **Security** and uncheck "*Scan device for Security threats*" and "*Improve harmful app detection*".