# Application installed on Android Lollipop, but blocked from running

Tags: android, permissions, android-5.1.1-lollipop

For this question, [how to disable google asking regularly checking app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265820/how-to-disable-google-asking-permission-to-regularly-check-installed-apps-on-my), there are answers like "uncheck the option Settings > Security > Verify apps". However, on **Lollipop I am using**, there is no such an option, instead there is an option "Unknown sources".

I unchecked this "Unknown sources", and **I could have my app installed**. I was asked if "google can regularly check installed apps for potentially harmful behavior". I clicked allow (*by mistake*). Then I can not start my application. Every time I click my app to start it, it is going to run, but immediately, it is stopped by google.

Do you know where can I configure the android to allow my app to run?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best Wishes,
York

Comment: "However, on Lollipop I am using, there is no such an option" -- try Google Settings.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.  Please use [android stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use settings.

On your device, open the Google Settings app(not android settings app);

Touch Security.

Move the switch next to "Improve harmful app detection" on or off.